# How to setup typescript development workflow in visual studio 2013?

Tags: javascript, workflow, typescript

I am using the typescript 0.9.1.1 in visual studio 2013 preview. I have a couple of questions about typescript development workflow.

1: How to let visual studio compile all typescript files into only one javascript source file.

2: How to generate the minified javascript file?

3: Could we have google closure "exportsymbol" feature in the typescript? If I want to all symbols in my_public_api.ts is kept as they are and all other symbol names should be obfuscated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.) How to let visual studio compile all typescript files into only one javascript source file.

You need to add the section `<TypeScriptOutFile>Some.js</TypeScriptOutFile>` to your project file manually.

> 2) How to generate the minified javascript file?

TypeScript compiler cannot do this. Use uglify.js OR google closure OR WebEssentials can
 do this for you.

> 3.) Could we have google closure "exportsymbol" feature in the typescript? If I want to all symbols in my_public_api.ts is kept as
>   they are and all other symbol names should be obfuscated.

TypeScript compiler does not do any minification / obfuscation.